# What is the syntax to tell C# I want my number to be considered as a decimal?

Tags: c#, syntax, decimal

I have a method

```
public void MyMethod(decimal val)
{

}
```

I want to call this method like this

MyMethod(4.6)

and it's not happy, presumably, it's thinking 4.6 is a double, not a decimal. What is a way to get it to recognize it as a decimal without having to go Convert.ToDecimal(4.6)

Comment: Or if you really don't like yourself `(decimal)4.6`

Comment: "and it's not happy" -- is that what the compiler error says ;)

Comment: Consider marking an answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`MyMethod(4.6m)`

Answer (score 7):

Use decimal literals: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx

```
decimal myMoney = 99.9m;
```

Answer (score 4):

**You will have to suffix M or m at de end of the literal.**

Eg:

```
 decimal myValue = 70.5M; //70.5m
 double doubleValue = 98.99;
```

And while calling, you do

```
 MyMethod(myValue );
```

In case of doubles

```
MyMethod((decimal)doubleValue); //i.e you cannot suffix M to a non-literal

MyMethod(doubleValueM);  // Is wrong
```

Comment: Oh damn, 3 answers in 10 seconds! ..this was a no-brainer i think.

Comment: hehe i figured it was quicker than actually looking it up in google

Comment: I couldn't believe my luck when I saw this question at the top of the page, with no answers yet!

Answer (score 1):

For decimal input with correct precision use m or M at the end of the literal value

like if you need to pass 4.6 than use 4.6m as parameter.